# How to send a mail from "meteor.com" using g-mail?

Tags: email, meteor

At first, I tried on localhost to send a mail using gmail, and I successed.
Then I deploied the program to "meteor.com".
Access the page and run the same code as which I successed on localhost.

And I got an error like below.

> Error invoking Method 'insertAnswer': Internal server error [500]
>     745f323d09652eaa945cf50eb68b4120191bb6cc.js:3

Of Course, beforehand, I set the environment like below in `ServerSideSetup`.

```
"process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://username%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
```

How to send a mail from "`meteor.com`" using `gmail` as same as using localhost ?

`insertAnswer` is a server-side method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertAnswer': function(answer){
        //Answers.insert(answer);
        var sendObj = {
            'to':'destination@gmail.com' ,
            'from':'username@gmail.com' ,
            'Reply-To':'username@gmail.com' ,
            'subject':'subject' ,
            'text':'text'
        };
        Email.send(sendObj);
    }
});
```

Comment: "insertAnswer" is a serverSide method like this.

Meteor.methods({
  'insertAnswer':function(answer){
    //Answers.insert(answer);

    var sendObj = {
      'to':'destination@gmail.com'
    ,  'from':'username@gmail.com'
    ,  'Reply-To':'username@gmail.com'
    ,  'subject':'subject'
    ,  'text':'text'
    };

    Email.send(sendObj);
  }
});

Comment: Make sure to `check()` your arguments when creating Meteor Methods: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods

Comment: Thank you.  
check(to,String); check(from,String);......  
I tried it but same error occured.

Comment: You're checking the argument that you're sending into `insertAnswer`, which is `answer` from `function(answer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail security check causes the error.
"Google account help" suggest 3 points. I did all of them and my code works as I expected.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a proper answer, you should let people know some brief information about your solution :/